# How do I correctly fromat this div's contents?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to improve my basic design "skills". I'm attempting to recreate this:
[image: figure]
but I don't know how to format it correctly with the right css.

```css
.container {
    width: 40%;
    height: 107px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#container h3, p {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="cover" src="book.png" width="45" height="60"/>
    <h3>Title of Something</h3>
    <p> Cracking the code </p>
    <img class="icon" src="icon.png" width="45" height="40"/>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Axel, thank you for the comment, you're right. But I've been on this website awhile now and I make sure to never ask questions unless I just can't seem to get it right, I've done a lot of CSS and HTML so far but I just can't get over this particular problem...

Comment: "I've done a lot of CSS and HTML so far", and using absolute positioning? Doesn't look like. Probably, you have done that "a lot CSS and HTML" with wrong tutorials, and there be better to start from scratch

Comment: @ankhzet dude when someone asking the question, just answer it. This really making me sad to see this type of people. Be humble brother. Be humble

Comment: At least I received proper English tutorials :)

Comment: @SteveGates nice try, bu SO is not for writing code instead of you. State what you want to achieve, what you have done so far, **and what's wrong** with gotten results, that you don't understand

Comment: @SteveGates, it would be strange if it did not get in an English speaking country, yeah? But we going into off-topic...

Comment: Like i say humble is the key.

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz, whats wrong with "Looks like you learned CSS with wrong tutorials"? Unhumble? Where? Somebody screws his education and you say "Splendid! Keep going! Here's, take this crutch to continue your path to the abyss!". Ni-i-ice...

Comment: i have to agree with @ankhzet

Comment: To be honest, when I look back, this was a very silly dispute. I accept my part in asking a 'silly question', I'm also sorry ankhzet for ridiculing your English, it was immature. SO is a great community to learn and I'm glad I can seek guidance in people like Axel and Fiido. Thank you and sorry :)

Comment: you are very welcome :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the way to fix the issue, your html working fine
only the css need to be edit.

CSS

```
.container {
width: 40%;
height: 107px;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
    float:left
}

.cover {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 5px;
}

.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
top: 15px
}

h3, p {
color: #000;
position: relative;
left: 60px;
top: 15px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb2hsnc9/)

Comment: if there anything you need help just contact me. :)

Comment: @SteveGates be careful with CSS: `position: absolute;` !

Comment: see what happens when you scale down the browser window

Comment: I know @Axel i aware that before . Actually i going do the way you did. well there is many way to accomplish this layout.  :)

Answer (score -1):

here is a very simple solution: http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/oXRVxG

#### HTML

```
<header>
  <img id=img-book alt=book src=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png width=158 height=158>
  <div id=title>
    <h3>Title of Something</h3>
    <p id=h1-sub>Title of Something</p>
  </div>
  <img id=img-face alt=book src=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png width=158 height=158>
</header
```

#### CSS

```
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 950px;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 90%;
}

#img-book, #title {
  float: left;
}

#img-face {
  float: right;
}
```